# Updating and join on multiple rows, which row's value is used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have the following statement and the inner join results in 3 rows where a.Id = b.Id, but each of the 3 rows have different b.Value's.  Since only one row from tableA is being updated, which of the 3 values is used in the update?

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Value = b.Value
FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB as b 
ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Comment: @bluefeet - Always?  I'd have thought this behaviour would be index-optimization dependent.  That is, ordering in SQL isn't guaranteed in `SELECT` statements unless an `ORDER BY` clause is specified.  And unfortuanately, this behaviour isn't trivially testable.  The fact that it doesn't throw an error (for something like 'statement returned more than one result') bugs me, too.  I'm a little leery of `JOIN`s on `UPDATE`s, for this reason (even though it may have simplified some of the things I needed to do in DB2).

Comment: You have no data to test this? Seems like you should be able to tell everyone else.

Comment: @X-Zero, I can confirm that an update with one row joined on multiple rows is non-deterministic.  How is this possible?  When I think of computers, I think deterministic, this is just kind of unusual for me.

Comment: @JeffO - I'm on DB2 (on an iSeries), which doesn't support this syntax.  But the larger problem is that you have to run tests until the optimizer picks a _different_ path, something over which you (pretty much) have no direct control - you can attempt to influence it by which indicies are created, and the distribution of data, but this is **no** guarantee of which order it would actually use.  You could use the exact same data set on two different machines, and get two different results, simply because one machine had more ram.

Comment: @sooprise - Computers are always deterministic, and there's no way to change this behaviour - witness the difficulty in generating 'random' numbers.  This includes the optimization of the `JOIN` order; However, it _appears_ non-deterministic, because you haven't (or are able to) reviewed all the available factors the system considers when running the statement.  Usually, this is a **good** thing - it allows the DBMS to choose a 'better' path without having to inform or otherwise affect you.  This is equivalent to functions that choose between sort routines - users just want data sorted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think there are rules for this case and you cannot depend on a particular outcome.

If you're after a specific row, say the latest one, you can use `apply`, like:

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.Value = b.Value
FROM    tableA AS a
CROSS APPLY
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    tableB as b
        where   b.id = a.id
        order by
                DateColumn desc
        ) as b
```

Answer (score 9):

Usually what you end up with in this scenario is the first row that appears in the order of the physical index on the table. In actual practice, you should treat this as non-deterministic and include something that narrows your result to one row.

Comment: Absolutely, this is something that I have learned now.  I'm just curious to know what my queries was doing before I fixed it.

Comment: Me too, @sooprise

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with using SQL Server 2008

```
--drop table #b
--drop table #a
select 1 as id, 2 as value
into #a

select 1 as id, 5 as value
into #b

insert into #b
select 1, 3

insert into #b
select 1, 6

select * from #a
select * from #b

UPDATE #a 
SET #a.Value = #b.Value
FROM #a
INNER JOIN #b 
ON #a.Id = #b.Id
```

It appears that it uses the top value of a basic select each time (row 1 of select * from #b). So, it possibly depends on indexing. However, I would not rely on the implementation set by SQL, as that has the possibility of changing. Instead, I would suggest using the solution presented by Andomar to make sure you know what value you are going to choose.

In short, do not trust the default implementation, create your own. But, this was an interesting academic question :)

Comment: I would appreciate to know why I got the downvote for those who downvoted my answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

Best option in my case for updating multiple records is to use merge Query(Supported from SQL Server 2008), in this query you have complete control of what you are updating.
Also you can use output query to do further processing.

Example: Without Output clause(only update)

```
;WITH cteB AS
( SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, Col3  
  FROM B WHERE Id > 10  ---- Select Multiple records
)
MERGE A
USING cteB
ON(A.Id = cteB.Id) -- Update condition
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET  
A.Col1 = cteB.Col1,  --Note: Update condition i.e; A.Id = cteB.Id cant appear here   again.
A.Col2 = cteB.Col2,
A.Col3 = cteB.Col3;
```

Example: With OputPut clause

```
CREATE TABLE #TempOutPutTable
  {
  PkId INT NOT NULL,
  Col1 VARCHAR(50),
  Col2 VARCHAR(50)
  }

;WITH cteB AS
( SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM B WHERE Id > 10
)
MERGE A
USING cteB
ON(A.Id = cteB.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET  
A.Col1 = cteB.Col1, 
A.Col2 = cteB.Col2,
A.Col3 = cteB.Col3
OUTPUT 
 INSERTED.Id, cteB.Col1, A.Col2 INTO #TempOutPutTable;

--Do what ever you want with the data in temporary table
SELECT * FROM #TempOutPutTable; -- you can check here which records are updated.
```

Comment: For completeness's sake, `UPDATE`, too, supports `OUTPUT`, and gives you "complete control of what you're updating": the key difference (in this update-only context) is that *`MERGE` will fail if multiple rows match, as opposed to picking one (effectively) at random*

Comment: I agree simple update statement can have output clause to know the records updated,
and the MERGE query will fail when we update a single record multiple time.
In usual case we should try to update a single record once, as updating multiple time will only retain the last value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I came up with a similar experiment to Justin Pihony:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #test ;
SELECT 
1 AS Name, 0 AS value 
INTO #test

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#compare') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #compare ;
SELECT 1 AS name, 1 AS value
INTO #compare
INSERT INTO #compare
SELECT 1 AS name, 0 AS value;

SELECT * FROM #test
SELECT * FROM #compare

UPDATE t
SET t.value = c.value
FROM #test t
INNER JOIN #compare c
    ON t.Name = c.name
```

Takes the topmost row in the comparison, right-side table. You can reverse the #compare.value values to 0 and 1 and you'll get the reverse.  I agree with the posters above...its very strange that this operation does not throw an error message as it is **completely hidden** that this operation IGNORES secondary values