# SQL Subquery returns more than one result in copy data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to copy a number from a table where the status is `9` to where the status is `8`

This is what the table currently looks like:

```
   REF   STATUS   number
   ab12   9        3452
   ab12   8        
   cd23   9        2112
   cd23   8
```

SQL:

```
SELECT     
    [REF]
    ,[STATUS]
    ,(select [number] 
        FROM table 
        where [REF] in 
                (select [REF] 
                   from table 
                  where [number] = '' 
                    and [STATUS] = '8') 
          and [STATUS] = '9')
 FROM [table]
```

I would like it to return something like:

```
 REF   STATUS   number
 ab12  8        3452 
 cd23  8        2112
```

However, because my subquery `select [REF] from table where [number] = '' and [STATUS] = '8'`
returns more than one row it won't work

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to `UPDATE` the original table, you can do this:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.number = s.number
FROM [table] t
INNER JOIN [table] s
ON t.REF = s.REF
AND s.status = 9
WHERE t.status = 8
AND t.number = ''
```

Comment: This is quite dangerous, because it's not clear which value will be set for number (3452 or 2112?)

Comment: It will copy the number that has status 9 to the same REF that has the status 8.  See screenshot: http://puu.sh/6BskA.png

Comment: @TTeeple this is exactly what i was looking for, but how can I only update the ones that are blank?

Comment: @neeko Add `AND t.number = ''` to the `WHERE`.  I updated the answer to reflect the new criteria.

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. That said, UPDATE with JOIN is generally dangerous because, surprisingly, it doesn't warn you if two values match for a given update (compare with MERGE), rather one will be applied arbitrarily

Comment: @MarkSowul thanks for your concern, could you explain what you mean by this? Do you mean that if it finds two References numbers the same it will apply the same number to each?

Comment: Let's say there was an additional fifth row: `cd23 9 2113`, so now there are two possibilities for what `number` to apply to `cd23 8 `: 2112 or 2113. Which one you get depends on the whims of the SQL gods. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9502449/155892

Comment: @MarkSowul Good thought.  I hadn't considered that initially since his test data showed just one line for each.  Thanks for keeping me in check!

Answer (score 2):

You can try joining the table on itself.

```
SELECT
    t.REF,
    t2.STATUS,
    t.number
FROM [table] t
    INNER JOIN [table] t2 ON t.REF = t2.REF
WHERE t.STATUS = 9
    AND t2.STATUS = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

A join is a common solution in this case, but it is possible to use a subquery like you tried to do, only it would need to be correlated with the main query.

Let's start with the fact that you (seem to) want to return status 8 rows only, and probably only those with an empty `number`:

```
SELECT
  REF,
  STATUS,
  number
FROM [table]
WHERE STATUS = 8
  AND number = ''
;
```

At this point you want to replace the `NUMBER` value with the one that a row with the same `REF` and the status of 9 has. (I'm assuming here that the same `REF` cannot have more than one row with the same status.) So, you'll need to put a subquery there that would use the `REF` value from the main query. But since you will be reading from the same table, you will need to distinguish between the two instances. You can assign an alias to either of them or to each (might be a better idea in the long run), so, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
  REF,
  STATUS,
  number = (
    SELECT number
    FROM [table] AS t2
    WHERE t2.REF = t1.REF
      AND t2.STATUS = 9
  )
FROM [table] AS t1
WHERE STATUS = 8
  AND number = ''
;
```

And if you actually want to *update* rows instead of just *returning* them, the above query can be easily changed to an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE t1
SET
  number = (
    SELECT number
    FROM [table] AS t2
    WHERE t2.REF = t1.REF
      AND t2.STATUS = 9
  )
FROM [table] AS t1
WHERE STATUS = 8
  AND number = ''
;
```