# BigQuery update table with COALESCE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I've tried to follow a data cleaning tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rO7ztF4NtU&list=PLUaB-1hjhk8H48Pj32z4GZgGWyylqv85f&index=3&t=1093s) . The mentor uses SQL Server and I use BigQuery (too much trouble install SQL Server on a Mac and I would like learn to adapt SQL syntax to BigQuery).

When it was instructed in SQL Server how to Populate Property Address data, the SQL syntax is

```sql
Select *
From PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing
--Where PropertyAddress is null
order by ParcelID



Select a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, ISNULL(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
From PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing a
JOIN PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.[UniqueID ] <> b.[UniqueID ]
Where a.PropertyAddress is null


Update a
SET PropertyAddress = ISNULL(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
From PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing a
JOIN PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.[UniqueID ] <> b.[UniqueID ]
Where a.PropertyAddress is null
```

I've managed to adapt some to BigQuery language

```sql
Select *
From `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData`
order by ParcelID
;

Select a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, COALESCE(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
From `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData` a
JOIN `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData` b
  on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
  AND a.UniqueID_ <> b.UniqueID_
Where a.PropertyAddress is null
;
```

But somehow got error when it comes to the below query

```sql
Update a
SET PropertyAddress = COALESCE(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
From sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData a
JOIN sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID_ <> b.UniqueID_ 
Where a.PropertyAddress is null
```

I've got Table "a" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).

Then I fix it by this

```sql
Update sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData
SET PropertyAddress = COALESCE(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
From sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData a
JOIN sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID_ <> b.UniqueID_ 
Where a.PropertyAddress is null
```

And got `UPDATE/MERGE` must match at most one source row for each target row

How do I fix this?

Comment: *When it was instructed in SQL* ... Did you mean Microsoft SQL Server? It is a misnomer to equate the language SQL with *one* RDBMS type that supports this language. Another misnomer is equating Git with Microsoft's GitHub.

Comment: The instructor use Microsoft SQL Management studio

Comment: Then it is SQL Server, a product like many others than run SQL including BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other DBMS's, SQL Server allows an update on multiple matching rows. However, without additional logic, such updates run only on first instance of joined matches based on indexes which is a non-deterministic outcome that can change with each run and hence not reliable.

Possibly, due to this scenario, BigQuery raises an error on such multi-row updates.

If goal is to populate missing property addresses with *any* non-missing property address by corresponding ParcelID, consider using an aggregate query.

Also, be sure to consistently use backticks as hyphen `-` in table names can raise syntax errors. Also, let's heed, [Bad Habits to Kick: Table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3), by using more informative aliases:

```sql
UPDATE `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData` nh
SET nh.PropertyAddress = agg.MaxPropertyAddress
FROM (
   SELECT
       ParcelID, 
       MAX(agg.PropertyAddress) AS MaxPropertyAddress
   FROM `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData`
   GROUP BY 
       ParcelID
) agg
WHERE nh.ParcelID = agg.ParcelID
  AND nh.PropertyAddress IS NULL
```

Comment: I still got UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Comment: Can you post sample data? SQL Server allows such an update but updates first instance of joined matches based on indexes which is a non-deterministic outcome and not reliable. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9502449/1422451. Other DBMSs like BigQuery raises an error with such update queries. What exactly are you trying to do? Clean missing property addresses with _any_ non-missing value by `ParcelID`?

Comment: See updated answer using an aggregate query.

Comment: Basically for the same ParcelID, there would be different UniqueID. The same ParcelID should have the same PropertyAddress. Some PropertyAddress rows are missing and I need to fill that. It's like in Excel I would use Vlookup to fill in the blank. From my understanding, JOIN would be the equivalent of Vlookup in SQL language hence the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I resort to ChatGPT and here's the solution

```
UPDATE 
    `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData`
SET 
    PropertyAddress = (
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
        FROM 
            `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData` AS a
        JOIN 
            `sturdy-filament-415311.NashvilleHousing.NHData` AS b
        ON 
            a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
            AND a.UniqueID_ <> b.UniqueID_
        WHERE 
            a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
            AND a.PropertyAddress IS NULL
        LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE 
    PropertyAddress IS NULL;
```

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?